# Modified double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference

Imagine instead of an opaqe screen with 2 slits, we have a mirror with 2 slits. Would this produce an interference pattern both on the screens behind and in front of the mirror? We still don't know which slits is the path taken.

Comment: Why would the mirror matter at all?

Comment: @InertialObserver: mirror reflects some of the photon back towards the incoming photon from the source, so I expect something to happen.

Comment: I can imagine if you set the mirror an integer wavelength apart (due to the phase shift at the plane) you would get destructive in reference along the lines where the beam wasn’t getting through anyways.. so I can’t imagine you would see any differences on the screen..I’ll post as answer tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have interference both in the transmitted light (behind the mirror) and in the reflected light (in front of the mirror).  But the interference would look different, because in essence the interference pattern in front of the mirror would be a bright area with dark fringes, while the interference pattern behind the mirror would be the usual dark area with bright fringes.

The pattern you would get in front of the mirror would be exactly the same as you would get by shining light past two opaque "ribbons" (the same shape and position as the slits) in a clear aperture.